# XSLT 2.0: Template match only if child element's value matches regex

Tags: xslt-2.0

Given this XML

```
<root>
    <card>
        <k>заада</k>
        <blockquote>заада I</blockquote>
        <blockquote>ир.</blockquote>
        <blockquote>(или жүрөк заада)</blockquote>
    </card>
    ...
</root>
```

I am trying to get only those `Card`s where any child `blockquote` element's value matches a regex. The XSL below isn't working, and I know why it doesn't work, I just can't figure out how to make it work.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//card[matches(blockquote, '^\w+-? I:?$')]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="card">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That code should give you a clear error message. It is not clear what you want to achieve but if you want to check that at least one `blockquote` child matches the regular expression then select `card[blockquote[matches(., '^\w+-? I:?$')]]`. For all use e.g. `card[every $bq in blockquote matches($bq, '^\w+-? I:?$')]`.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to understand the error message, I just didn't know that I can nest square bracket filters 